# Handling a looooong HTTP request (currently using axios)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have a server that converts large files and uploads the results to cloud storage. Today I finally hit that limit, where conversion took over a minute and upload took 2 more, resulting in a very long HTTP request. Client is React using axios to call an Express server.

What I'm experiencing on the server side is that after about 2 minutes, the request gets called again (with no user input). Both requests then fail on the client (yet succeed on the server). The result is 2 conversions of the same file, and 2 useless uploads, since the client gets notified of an error.

I believe that what I'm seeing is a try-timeout-abort-retry-timeout-abort sequence. I tried passing a `{timeout: 5 * 60 * 1000}` to axios to get 5 minutes timeout - to no avail.

We're planning to change the process to be async, out-of-band, Web Sockets, etc. But until then, how can I ensure the request won't fail? Is there a browser-level setting I need to handle? Or use a different library than axios?

Comment: Check https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1503 , it might be an issue with your server rather than Axios

Comment: I'm not familiar with Axios, but in general, the browser will wait indefinitely if an HTTP connection has been established.  I've had AJAX requests take hours in the past that eventually succeed.  Chances are, your server or a reverse proxy or something is timing out.  Can you post a packet capture?

Comment: Is an option for you increase the time out in the Express Server? `server.timeout = 999999` (example in milliseconds)

Comment: I have a problem like that before.
The problem solved when I used async process.
You can return success status from server before the async process finished.

Comment: You could send the file then close the request and long poll for progress status while server does it's thing and updates session with it's progress

Comment: I had a similar issue, i ended up chunking the file into smaller chunks and reassembling server side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments - you guys nailed it. The abort was issued by Express. Adding `req.setTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000)` solved it. Thanks all!

Update: adding the timeout at the `server` level is even better:

```
//...express middleware + routs + etc...
const server = app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`);
});

//set timeout of requests to 5 minutes
server.timeout = 5 * 60 * 1000;
```